# How to work on Javascript projects?

Tags: javascript, aptana

I am trying to write my own Javascript Framework something like jQuery.

I use Aptana Studio for designing websites. I was planning to create a web page and write the Javascript code just as we would do for a website. Then I noticed that Aptana Studio also has a Javascript Project. So I created a new Javascript Project. But it primarily allows you to create only .js files and no HTML files. I wonder what a standalone .js file would do? Would't I need an HTML file to execute and test my Javascript code?

Certainly there must be some advantage to using the Javascript Project. But I am not able to figure it out. Can someone please explain how to use the Javascript Project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about Aptana Studio, but I'm guessing that you're intended to drive your JavaScript project from another project. Think of the JavaScript project like a self-contained library. It doesn't make sense to include the test code in the library itself, because consumers of the library probably don't want to deal with it. Try creating a second project that imports your JavaScript project and allows you to play with it and test it.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you try Javascript-Test Driver. It has an IDE support and also it seems to be fairly good at helping you debug code. Find more details here:
http://code.google.com/p/js-test-driver/

I would say that while you DO need HTML files; you'd probably wanna do more according to the testing framework you choose; as some work with fixtures other loads up iframe and stuff. But I would presume that writing a whole framework would take more than just HTML pages and a unit testing framework would be more apt for the req.

Screw Unit for JS
http://github.com/nkallen/screw-unit

I know I have deviated from your question; but I just felt that rather than right project structure and HTML for testing what would be more important is a testing framework that keeps development agile and fast.

But that's just me.